# Extract Id's from response.text()

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, libcurl, pycurl

I want to extract all the values of id's from the following response (finding).

code:

```
findings= requests.get('https://api.probely.com/targets/TaargetID/findings/36',headers={"Content-Type": "application/json", "Authorization": "JWT <Token>"})
finding=findings.json()
```

finding:

```
{"count":45,
   "page_total":5,
   "page":1,
   "length":10,
   "results":[
      {
         "id":79,
         "target":
             {"id":"RzXFSNHH3qUY","name":"","site": 
                 {"id":"2qk21XKLrKyf","url":"https://test- 
                 0.ox.qa.prbly.win",.....},
          "(...)"
         ,
         "id":12,
         "target":
          "(...)"
         ,
         "id":32,
         "target":
          "(...)"
         ,"(....)"
}
]
}
```

I want to get an array of id's like this:
 `id=[79,12,32]`
How can I extract these Id's and store in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use iteration to go over each item in "results", then save the IDs to an array.

```py
id_list = []

for result in finding["results"]:
    id_list.append(result["id"])
```

I'd also like to point out that you shouldn't call any variable `id` as it is a built in Python function, overwriting it could have bad consequences.

Comment: And how can I get the url of id:79?

Answer (score 0):

You can try it:

```
ids = list(map(lambda res: res["id"], finding["results"]))
```

What type of "results" key ? "id" field occurs several times

Comment: And how can I get the url of id:79?